# Error while migrating contracts to Ropsten using truffle - Error: legacy access request rate exceeded

Tags: solidity, truffle, ropsten, truffle-migration

I'm deploying some contract to Ropsten ethereum test network using Truffle but it gave me this error:

```
Error: legacy access request rate exceeded
```

I have no idea what does it means and what should I do with it. Before I migrated the contract to my local blockchain and it worked.

I migrate 2 contracts and 1 library. 1 contract passes correctly, but library fails and contract using library fails as well.

Comment: can you provide the actual code library and contract that fail abd your mìgration file?

Comment: I received the same error message. Then I tried to deploy the contract again and it worked.

Comment: this is the [library](https://github.com/Sikorkaio/sikorka/blob/master/contracts/trigonometry.sol) and the contract is simple contract using this library. But it fails only sometimes and even when it fails, it is deployed, so Im confused.

Answer (score 2):

there!
I had a same error, and i created new infura project to get new token, then it went well!

reference:
https://community.infura.io/t/legacy-key-deprecation/443

Answer (score 0):

Infura updated their API a few days ago. That is causing this error.